# How to get each Bar CGMutablePathRef in Bar chart created by using Core Plot?

Tags: iphone

I found below method in existing framework. Can any one please suggest me how can i use this method

-(CGMutablePathRef)newBarPathWithContext:(CGContextRef)context recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got solution for above question, For above method pass bar index as a parameter and We can pass context parameter as NULL. Then we will get the corresponding bar CGMutablePathRef.